# GetAttributes() Not Returning All Attributes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, xunit

I'm trying to write a test that checks I can deserialise all of my enums with the `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonEnumConverter))]` attribute,

So I've got this (in-progress) test generator code:

```
private class TestDataGenerator: IEnumerable<object[]>
{

    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var allEnums = typeof(RecordType).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsEnum);
        var testEnums = allEnums.Where(e => e.GetCustomAttributes().Any(a => a is JsonConverter));
        var enumMemberInfo = testEnums.SelectMany(e => e.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public));
        IEnumerable<object[]> enumsWithNames = enumMemberInfo.Select(e =>
                                                                     {
                                                                         Enum.TryParse(e.Name, out RecordType res);
                                                                         return new object[]
                                                                                {
                                                                                    res,
                                                                                    ((JsonPropertyNameAttribute)e.GetCustomAttributes().First(a => a is JsonPropertyNameAttribute)).Name
                                                                                };
                                                                     });
        return enumsWithNames.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

If I scrap the `testEnums.SelectMany` and run it with `typeof(RecordObject)` directly, this works.

So jumping on the debugger, the issue seems to be that `testEnums` evaluates to nothing. If I then look at `allEnums[0].GetCustomAttributes()`, the `[JsonConverter(T)]` is nowhere to be seen.

Here's my enum:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))] 
public enum RecordType
{
        [JsonPropertyName("country")]
        Country = 1,

        [JsonPropertyName("destinationOrbit")]
        DestinationOrbit = 2,

        // etc
}
```

Any ideas why this attribute apparently doesn't exist on my enum and how I can get this info at runtime?

Comment: @gunr2171 - Easily done :)

The weird thing is, I know the attribute is there because if I do `typeof(myEnum).GetCustomAttributes()` I can see it... It just doesn't seem to work going through `Assembly.GetTypes()` which is confusing me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to filter by `JsonConverterAttribute` instead of `JsonConverter`

```
var testEnums = allEnums.Where(e => e.GetCustomAttributes().Any(a => 
            a is JsonConverterAttribute));
```

Visual Studio will only display `JsonConverter` instead of `JsonConverterAttribute` above the class, but if you hover your cursor over the type then you will see the full name.

The `JsonConverter` is a different type.

Comment: Yeah...  I should've known that... Cheers!

Not sure what all the debugger weirdness was about though but at least this works